# Java, mapping a JSON's keys

Tags: java, json

Here's what I wanna do
I have a json, like:

```
{
  "demoNumber":123,
  "demoText":"asdasdasd"
}
```

and I wanna make a simple String array from it, which should be

```
["demoNumber","demoText"]
```

In the app we're making the user can add any type of data, so we can't do data models for everything, that's not an option

I have added json to my Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.json:json:20180130'
}
```

But it still can't find the method.

What I tried:

```
JSONObject jo = null;
try {
    jo = new JSONObject(
        "{\"city\":\"chicago\",\"name\":\"jon doe\",\"age\":\"22\"}"
    );
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Set<String> keys = jo.toMap().keySet();
```

And I still get the error: "Cannot resolve method 'toMap()'".
Gradle is imported, and I even downloaded the jar file which contains these, and added it to libs,
Android Studio still can't find the method.

Working solution:

```
ArrayList keyList = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator< ? > keys = jo.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        keyList.add(key);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `toMap()` method in `org.json`, just call `keySet()` on `JsonObject` directly

```
Set<String> keys = jo.keySet();
```

Documentation of the same [here](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#keySet--).

Below code works

```
import java.util.Set;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ExampleMainOne {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JSONObject jo = null;
    try {
        jo = new JSONObject("{\"city\":\"chicago\",\"name\":\"jon doe\",\"age\":\"22\"}");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Set<String> keys = jo.toMap().keySet();

    System.out.println(keys);    //[city, name, age]

    }

 }
```

Comment: are you missing import? @Fenyvesi can you tell exactly which library are you using?

Comment: It's a brand new, empty android studio project, I imported     compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'
in gradle, and in the java file, everything from org.json: import org.json.*;

Comment: i looked at documentation it has that method, remove this `org.json.*` and import only necessary ones @Fenyvesi

Comment: That's what i tried at first, imported JSONObject and JSONException, and still cannot find the method. Is there another import for it?

Comment: atleast check suggestion on `JSONObject` @Fenyvesi if you are using ide

Comment: it doesnt work for me. But I have found something that works, updated the post.